# Android Studio UI Scaling

Tags: windows, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to maunally scale the UI of Android Studio by following the following documents:

https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#customize_ide

The problem is I'm pretty sure I've followed them to the T, but the code in `idea.properties` isn't working. Here's the code:

```
# custom Android Studio properties

idea.hidpi=true
```

I've also tried `hidpi=true` to no avail.

I can't seem to find any more information about how to make this work. After it works, I'll need to manually change the DPI value because `true` sets it to `196`, but I'd like it to be `144`.

I'm not opposed to adding arguments to the `.exe` file. Any way to achieve this is a good way!

Thanks for your time,

Michael

Comment: @kreker, are you also interested in an answer for Windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in a solution for Windows.

Comment: Have you tried checking "Override high DPI scaling behavior"? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000556364-IntelliJ-magnifies-after-computer-sleeps?page=1#community_comment_115000479810 ?